# How to enter date, month, year in 3 different dropdowns more efficiently

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have just started out on automation and I am stuck on how I can have my date, month, year which are in 3 different drop downs with different xpaths entered in more efficient way such that I do not have to use select class for every single one of them

Here is the code :

```
package com.singh.assignment;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Json 
{  
    public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

try 
{

   Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dell\\eclipse-
workspace\\Assignment\\data.json"));

   JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) obj;


   String fname = (String) jsonObject.get("fname").getAsString();
   String lname = (String) jsonObject.get("lname").getAsString();
   String baseurl = (String) jsonObject.get("baseurl").getAsString();
   String mstatus = (String) jsonObject.get("mstatus").getAsString();


 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\WORK\\geckodriver.exe\\");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

   driver.get(baseurl);

   driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Registration")).click();

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id = 
'name_3_firstname']")).sendKeys(fname);

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id = 
'name_3_lastname']")).sendKeys(lname);

   List<WebElement> martial = driver.findElements(By.name("radio_4[]"));
   {
       for(WebElement radio : martial)
       {
           if(radio.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase(mstatus))
           {
               radio.click();
           }
       }
   }

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'reading']")).click();

   WebElement cntry = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id = 
  'dropdown_7']"));

   Thread.sleep(3000);

   Select index = new Select(cntry);

   index.selectByVisibleText("India");

   WebElement month = driver.findElement(By.id("mm_date_8"));

   Select index1 = new Select(month);

   index1.selectByVisibleText("9");

   WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.id("dd_date_8"));

   Select index2 = new Select(date);

   index2.selectByVisibleText("15");

   WebElement year = driver.findElement(By.id("dd_date_8"));

   Select index3 = new Select(year);

   index3.selectByVisibleText("1995");

}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }

}
```

And here is the JSON File :

```
  {
 "baseurl": "http://demoqa.com/",
 "fname": AKASHDEEP,
 "lname": SINGH,
 "mstatus": single,
 "hobby": ["Dance", "Reading", "Cricket"]

  }
```

Comment: More efficient way than what? you didn't post your code.

Comment: more efficient than having a select class for every dropdown of date month and year

Comment: Share your code along with HTML source sample

Comment: Shared the code and json file

Comment: I can't see anything to do with a date of birth in what you've shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that you need to completely revise your tests' implementation approach. An ideal test case shouldn't know anything about WebDriver, locators or hardcoded data. You should try building several abstraction layers to encapsulate driver calls within framework, locators within page objects, test data within external storage (plus entities and data providers).

If we talk about some basic optimization for your particular scenario, I'd start with creating some abstract page, which could hide explicit interactions with a WebDriver:

```
public abstract class AbstractPage {

    private final WebDriverWait wait;

    public AbstractPage() {
        // assuming some external driver provider
        this.wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 10);
    }

    public void selectByVisibleText(final By locator, final String text) {
        new Select(waitFor(locator, ExpectedConditions::visibilityOfElementLocated)).selectByVisibleText(text);
    }

    public void selectByVisibleText(final By locator, final int number) {
        selectByVisibleText(locator, String.valueOf(number));
    }

    private WebElement waitFor(final By locator, final Function<By, ExpectedCondition<WebElement>> condition) {
        return wait.until(condition.apply(locator));
    }
}
```

Then you can just create a page object for your domain logic, which will reuse common dropdown selection method:

```
public class HomePage extends AbstractPage {

    private By dropdownDate = By.id("date");
    private By dropdownMonth = By.id("month");
    private By dropdownYear = By.id("year");

    public HomePage selectDate(final LocalDate date) {
        selectByVisibleText(dropdownMonth, date.getMonthValue());
        selectByVisibleText(dropdownDate, date.getDayOfMonth());
        selectByVisibleText(dropdownYear, date.getYear());
        return this;
    }
}
```

And in your test case you'd just call `selectDate(date)`, which is much more concise and human readable way to express business logic.